# Display aws s3 file in laravel blade

Tags: laravel, amazon-s3

How can I display my file that I uploaded in my asw s3 bucket using laravel blade. This is what I tried but it dosen't show the file

```
  <video class="" id="cb"   style=" width:30%;  float:left; clear: left; margin-top:0px; padding-top:10px; cursor:pointer; height:auto;"><source  src="{{url('https://bucketbucket.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com' . Auth::user()->intro_video)}}#t=13" alt="Video Unavailable"   id="" ></source></video>
```

. I don't know if I am doing something wrong. Help me here please. Thanks in advance

Comment: "[...] but it dosen't work". *What* doesn't work? Are you getting an error? Please be specific.

Comment: @TimLewis thanks for replying. The file is not showing. I think I might me be doing something wrong I am not sure.

Comment: Check your console (F12) for errors; if the file is not showing, you might see a 404 error. Confirm that your path is correct to where the file is stored. Or there might be a 403 error, at which point you can't access it. Find that error and edit it into your question.

Comment: There is no error its just the video file is not displaying. The file is uploaded in my bucket and in the database. I think I'm doing somthing which is why its not displaying on the webpage

Comment: Never mind I found my issue thank you for your help!!:)

Comment: There should always be some kind of error/indication when something isn't happening when it should be :P Glad you got it working regardless. Also, feel free to answer your own question; someone else may find it useful.

Comment: @TimLewis Thank you. I just shared my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I found my problem.
Since aws s3 saves my file as a url All I had to do was put {{Auth::user()->intro_video}}  as my src.

```
<video class="" id="cb"   style=" width:30%;  float:left; clear: left; 
margin-top:0px; padding-top:10px; cursor:pointer; height:auto;"><source  
src="{{Auth::user()->intro_video}}" alt="Video Unavailable"   id="" > 
</source></video>
```

Hopfeully this helps someone